# Flask Rest API SQLAlchemy foreign key error

Tags: python, flask

I got SQLALchemy error, when I tried "flask db migrate"

```
NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'user.menu_id' could not find table 'menu' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id
```

Menu table

```
class Menu(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'menus'
   id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
   price = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
   description = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
   picture = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
   create_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
   users = db.relationship('User', backref="menu", lazy=True)
```

User table

```
class User(Model):
""" User model for storing user related data """

   id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   email = Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
   username = Column(db.String(15), unique=True, index=True)
   name = Column(db.String(64))
   password_hash = Column(db.String(128))
   admin = Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

   joined_date = Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)    
   userdataset = db.relationship("Dataset", backref="user", lazy="dynamic")
   menu_id = Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('menu.id'), nullable=False)
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

How can ı solve this problem? Where am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have renamed your 'Menu' table to 'menus' with this `__tablename__` property in your 'Menu' model:

```
__tablename__ = 'menus'
```

You then try to reference to the 'Menu' table, when in fact, its name has been changed to 'menus'. The simplest way to solve this would be to change your `User.menu_id` column to this:

```
menu_id = Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('menus.id'), nullable=False)
```

Another way of fixing this issue would be modifying the `__tablename__` property to 'menu'. (You could also just delete it.)